# Drag drop colors on a png image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

In an iOS application. I want to drag and drop images on my UIImageView where i have placed a png image. I just want these colors inside the image but not in transparent area. Attached images can explain my question more good

[image]

I want to drag an image from bottom and drop on the image and it should looks like this.

These colors on bottom may be considered as UIImageViews

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *) changeColorForImage:(UIImage *)image toColor:(UIColor*)color {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

CGRect contextRect;
contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;
contextRect.size = [image size];
// Retrieve source image and begin image context
CGSize itemImageSize = [image size];
CGPoint itemImagePosition;
itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);
itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) );

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Setup shadow
// Setup transparency layer and clip to mask
CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);
CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [image CGImage]);
// Fill and end the transparency layer

CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeColorDodge);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, color.CGColor);

contextRect.size.height = - contextRect.size.height;
contextRect.size.height -= 15;
CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);
CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(c);

UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;

}
```

I believe it'll help you.

Comment: this is really nice. It changes the whole colour of the image. but want to add color only in the particular area as it is described in the attached Image

Comment: you ought to draw these areas(4) with core graphics, but can't help you with drawing context. And change color separately